# Dynamically parsing through nested classes for values and attributes

Tags: c#, linq, parsing, class, reflection

I have several models that includes nested classes and lists. Many of the class members have attributes that I also have to read in.

I'm looking for a dynamic way (possibly through Linq or Reflection) to retrieve the values and attributes of all generic objects within the specified model.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Edit:

Using the ObjectManager as per x0r's suggestion, I can see all of the data. The remaining part of this issue requires member annotation. Is there some way to copy over the PropertyInfo of each class member?

```
ObjectWalker objectWalker = new ObjectWalker(objectToValidate);

foreach (Object o in objectWalker)
{
    if (isGeneric(o.GetType()))
    {    
        PropertyInfo property = o.GetType().GetProperty(o); // <-- This does not work... Need to obtain annotations somehow
        object[] Attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Attribute), true);

        foreach (Attribute attribute in Attributes)
        {
            // Annotations processing goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [ObjectWalker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.objectmanager%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

It helps you to parse an object graph and visit all unique elements. 
As you can see it stores only a stack of objects and Current returns an Object.

You could modify this so the Walker would save a class that contains all the data you need for each  property (Like a propertyinfo object or a list of attributes).